# $f$ is holomorphic in Ω such that $|f|^2$ is harmonic; we need to show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions

$f$ is holomorphic in Ω such that $|f|^2$ is harmonic; we need to show that $f$ is constant.

[solution of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hsaR.png)
In the solution attached, I don't really understand the transition between $∆|f(z)|^2 = 4|f'_z(z)|^2$.
It would be great someone could answer this.

Comment: Please keep the body of your question self-contained. It should be possible to read just the question without the title and still understand what's what.

Comment: Sorry for that! I'll edit it now :)

Comment: Do you know about the Wirtinger derivatives yet?

Comment: @DanielFischer I do know the definition of the linear partial differential operators of first order :)

Comment: Can you interpret $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$? Those are the Wirtinger derivatives (of $u$ in this case).

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes I do! I don't know how exactly to apply that to ∆.

Comment: Good. Then note that $$\Delta = 4\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}}.$$ Can you see that for holomorphic $f$ you have $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}} (f\cdot \overline{f}) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}} = f'\cdot \overline{f'}\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I get that Δ notation but I don't see it for $ f⋅f\bar$..

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations in complex form are simply $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$. And for holomorphic functions, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = f'$. By the product rule, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} (f \cdot \overline{f}) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}\cdot \overline{f} + f\cdot \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}}.$$ Since $f$ is holomorphic, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} (f \cdot \overline{f}) = f\cdot \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}} = f\cdot \overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}},$$

Comment: using $\frac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial \overline{z}} = \overline{\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}}$. Applying $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ to that then yields $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}} (f\cdot \overline{f}) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot \overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}$ since $\overline{f'}$ is antiholomorphic.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ then consider $h(x,y)=u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)=|f(z)|^2$

$h_{xx}=2(u_x)^2+2uu_{xx}+2(v_x)^2+2vv_{xx}$

$h_{yy}=2(u_y)^2+2uu_{yy}+2(v_y)^2+2vv_{yy}$

Then $∆|f(z)|^2=h_{xx}+h_{yy}=4((u_x)^2+(v_x)^2)=4|f'_z(z)|^2$ because of the Cauchy-Riemann equations and the fact that if $f$ is holomorphic then both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic

This gives us that $f'_z(z)=0$ (since $h=|f|^2$ is also harmonic from the hypothesis) and this means that $f$ is constant

Comment: You 're welcome! :)